<img> is not replaced with nextjs custom element defined in useMDXComponents
After reading the fantastic article about having mdx in nextjs I tried to implement the same approach in my nextjs 14 app, and also using the official instructions for custom elements to reformat some tags in my mdx files.
import Image, { ImageProps } from 'next/image';

import type { MDXComponents } from 'mdx/types';

export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    h2: ({ children }) => <h2 className="font-bold">{children}</h2>,
    img: (props) => <Image sizes="100vw" {...(props as ImageProps)} />,
    // img: (props) => <hr />, This is for testing if it picks img and replaces it with hr

    ...components,
  };
}


Using the config above, for a very simple markdown doc like the following, it will correctly replace the heading2 element (denoted as ##) with the defined h2 element (The className="font-bold"> is added to my output html document) However, <img> tag will not be substituted with the nextjs' <Image /> element (sizes="100vw" is not added)
I even tried to add a dummy img: (props) => <hr /> for my config to see if it picks up img tag and replaces it with hr, but no luck.
My Markdown:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

## This is my heading 2

<img src="/path/to/my/image.png" width="300" height="300" />

The rendered html:
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h2 class="font-bold">This is my heading 2</h2>
<img src="/path/to/my/image.png" width="300" height="300" />

I'm using next-mdx-remote with the following config in my [...slug]/page.tsx:
import { compileMDX } from 'next-mdx-remote/rsc';
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';

export default async function ArticlesPage({ params }: Params) {
  // Read the MDX file from the content source directory
  const source = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), contentSource, params.slug.join('/')) + '.mdx', 'utf8');

  // MDX accepts a list of React components
  const components = useMDXComponents({});

  // We compile the MDX content with the frontmatter, components, and plugins
  const { content, frontmatter } = await compileMDX({
    source,
    options: {
      mdxOptions: {
        // rehypePlugins: [rehypeSlug],
        // remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
      },
      parseFrontmatter: true,
    },
    components,
  });


  const pageTitle = frontmatter.title as string;
  const pageLastUpdate = frontmatter.lastUpdate as string;

  // Render the page
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
      <p className="text-sm italic">Last update: {pageLastUpdate}</p>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </>
  );
}


After spending a lot of time debugging this:
The problem
You can write a very simple function to log the AST of your markdown content and use it in your mdxOptions of your compileMDX function:
function logAst() {
  return (tree) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
    return tree;
  };
}

const { content, frontmatter } = await compileMDX({
  source,
  options: {
    mdxOptions: {
      rehypePlugins: [logAst],
    },
    parseFrontmatter: true,
  },
  components,
});

Then refresh your mdx page and the AST will be printed in your console. You would see that:

If you have an image with standard markdown syntax like ![Alt Text](/image.png) in AST it would be recognized as "type": "element"
While if you have the image tag as <img src="/image.png" /> it would be logged as "type": "mdxJsxFlowElement".

That simply means if you have defined some custom components like below, it will not transform your <img /> tags:
import Image, { ImageProps } from 'next/image';

export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    ...components,
    img: (props) => <Image sizes="100vw" {...(props as ImageProps)} />;
    }
  };
}

Solution
In your mdx file, you should use a custom image tag like <NextImage /> and in your custom component replace img with NextImage:
import Image, { ImageProps } from 'next/image';

export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    ...components,
    NextImage: (props) => <Image sizes="100vw" {...(props as ImageProps)} />;
    }
  };
}

